# Find the computational complexity for the following loops

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

[image: code]

```
For n=1 : Inner loop will execute 1 time.
For n=2 : Inner loop will execute 1+2 times.
For n=4 : Inner loop will execute 1+2+4 times.
For n=8 : Inner loop will execute 1+2+4+8 times.
```

.
.
.

So how can I find the computational complexity?

My answer is : 
Number of inner loop iterations = n+(n/2)+(n/4)+(n/8)+...+(n/n)

Comment: Shouldn't it read `For n=1,2,3,4` instead of `For n=1,2,4,8`? And the number of operations executed is then 2^n-1?

Comment: I choose n=1,2,4,8... to make it easier to find the complexity because i=i*2. I don't know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total time complexity is Θ(n). To see this, note that the inner loop does Θ(i) work per iteration, and that i takes on the values 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ..., 2<sup>log n</sup>. If we sum this up, using the formula for the sum of a geometric series, we get

> 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2<sup>log n</sup> = 2<sup>log n + 1</sup> - 1 = 2 · 2<sup>log n</sup> - 1 = 2n - 1

So the total work done is Θ(n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.
But why 2^logn not n ?

Comment: @ammarx- Assuming we are using base-2 logarithms, those are identical.

Answer (score 2):

You can formally proceed like the following to obtain both the exact number of instructions that will execute, as well as the order of growth:

[image]